# dart: dart:convert with 'package:json_annotation: jsonEncode and jsonDecode fails on enum

Tags: json, dart

I created the enum

```
enum EFileCreateMode {
  create(0),
  append(1),
  insert(2);

  final int _iIndex;
  const EFileCreateMode(this._iIndex);

  static String infoStr() {
    String InfoStr = "";
    for (EFileCreateMode entry in values) {
      String newEntry = "${entry._iIndex}(${entry.name})";
      if (InfoStr.isEmpty) {
        InfoStr = newEntry;
      } else {
        InfoStr = "$InfoStr,$newEntry";
      }
    }
    return InfoStr;
  }

  String jsonString() {
    var encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent("  ");
    String JsonString = encoder.convert(this);
    return JsonString;
  }
}
```

to be included in my test-class

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'c_version_info_file.dart';
part 'e_file_create_mode_test.g.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
@JsonSerializable()
class EFileCreateModeTest {
  String EFileCreateModeInfo = EFileCreateMode.infoStr();
  late EFileCreateMode eFileCreateMode;

  EFileCreateModeTest() {
    eFileCreateMode = EFileCreateMode.create;
  }

  String jsonString() {
    var encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent("  ");
    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    String JsonString = encoder.convert(this);
    return JsonString;
  }

  /// Connect the generated [_$EFileCreateModeTestFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory EFileCreateModeTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$EFileCreateModeTestFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$EFileCreateModeTestFromJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$EFileCreateModeTestToJson(this);
}
```

which i want to test with the routine

```
static int runTest() {
    EFileCreateModeTest eFileCreateModeTest =EFileCreateModeTest();
    String jsonString = eFileCreateModeTest.jsonString(), jsonString2;
    String testFileName = "EFileCreateModeTest.cVi";

    // Write Struct with enum as JSON to file
    try {
      if (File(testFileName).existsSync()) {
        // If file exists, dont overwrite
        // Allows manual modifications for testing
        print("OK: File $testFileName already exists");
      }
      else {
        // Write file, if not existing
        File(testFileName).writeAsStringSync(jsonString);
        print("OK: File $testFileName written");
      } 
    } catch (e) {
      // Somethings gone wrong writing the file
      print("FATAL: Write Test failed with $e");
      return -1;
    }

    // Read Struct from file
    EFileCreateModeTest newEFileCreateModeTest;
    try {
      jsonString2 = File(testFileName).readAsStringSync();
    } catch (e) {
      print("FATAL: Read Test from file $testFileName\n"
        "\tfailed with $e");
      return -1;
    }
    try {
      // Try to decode the JSON just generated
      newEFileCreateModeTest = jsonDecode(jsonString2);
    } catch (e) {
      print("FATAL: Decode Test failed with $e");
      return -1;
    }

    if (eFileCreateModeTest == newEFileCreateModeTest) {
      print("OK: Comparison SUCCESSFUL");
      return 0;
    }

    print("LAST FAIL: Comparison FAILED");
    return -1;
  }
```

**Result:**

My tests failed:

1. writing EFileCreateModeTest instance as JSON to file and read again unchanged generates the error:  Decode Test failed with type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'EFileCreateModeTest'
2. Also changing the JSON entry <"eFileCreateMode": "create"> to <"eFileCreateMode": 0> or "eFileCreateMode": "EFileCreateMode.create" result in the same error

So, if i want to initialize a EFileCreateModeTest instance from a JSON string successfully, how to do it?

Sorry, what i forgot to mention about the standard JSON output of a EFileCreateModeTest instance is:

{
"EFileCreateModeInfo": "0(create),1(append),2(insert)",
"eFileCreateMode": "create"
}

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some tries and research i recognized my mistake:
The wrong codeline

```
newEFileCreateModeTest = jsonDecode(jsonString2);
```

has to be replaced with this:

```
newEFileCreateModeTest = EFileCreateModeTest.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString2));
```

Then recreation of the EFileCreateModeTest instance from the JSON string saved in the file works errorfree.